# When can high order small quantities be dropped?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I came across this in a book:

$$ z\left( \varepsilon\right){\rm{ }} = {\rm{ }}1{\rm{ }} + {\rm{ }}H\varepsilon {\rm{ }} + {\rm{ }}O\left( {{\varepsilon ^2}} \right)\ $$

$$H{\rm{ }} \equiv {\rm{ }}{z^\prime}\left( 0 \right)$$

$$z\left( t \right){\rm{ }} = {\rm{ }}\mathop {lim}\limits_{N \to \infty } {\rm{ }}{\left[ {z\left( {t/N} \right)} \right]^N}{\rm{ }} = {\rm{ }}\mathop {lim}\limits_{N \to \infty } {\left[ {1{\rm{ }} + {\rm{ }}H\left( {t/N} \right)} \right]^N}{\rm{ }} = {\rm{ }}e{{\rm{ }}^{Ht}}$$
The author brings the first expression into the third expression and then drops the higher order term. My question is when can I drop the higher order term? In particular, why can I leave out higher order terms here?

Comment: squeeze theorem

Comment: You can take logarithms. $N\ln(1+Ht/N+O(t^2/N^2))=Ht+O(t^2/N)\to Ht$.

Comment: @FShrike，thankyouverymuch ,help me a lot